# Get cluster-health from etcd api

Tags: etcd

From the command line, I can run the following command to get the cluster health of an `etcd` cluster, like this:

```
etcdctl cluster-health
member ac92bd2949b92e96 is healthy: got healthy result from https://172.31.26.170:2379
member bebdb18e18d35331 is healthy: got healthy result from https://172.31.21.117:2379
member c1c4d5cb0d474453 is healthy: got healthy result from https://172.31.18.126:2379
```

However, I can't seem to find the same functionality documented in the [API specification](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/v2/api.html).  How do I programmatically determine if a cluster is healthy from the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from Github, thought I would pass it along-

There is no single API call which returns the cluster health for all nodes in the cluster.  In order to do this, you need to:

1. Make a call to the [members API](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/v2/members_api.html) to get a list of all of the members in the cluster.
2. Make a call to the [admin API](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/v2/admin_guide.html) to get the health of each endpoint.

Comment: the links does not open to corresponding apis, can you please update that

Answer (score 3):

`etcdctl cluster-health` is deprecated in V3, you can use the command below instead:

`etcdctl --cluster=true endpoint health`

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was about an API which corresponds with this CLI command.